# Execute Function on Constructor PHP

Tags: php, mysql

i have class called dbconnection. I want to call this connection function in the constructor. Usually in Java, i just declare:

```
private FileName variable = new Filename();
```

and assign the variable.logOn on any functions.

But now, in authenticate php class, i couldn't do that. So i think i can execute the connection in constructor, I've tried:

```
public function __construct(){
  $conn = new Database();
}
```

but i couldn't access the $conn var because it's not global variable.

Another method i use is placing below code outside any function.

```
 public $conn  = new Database();
```

but it shows an error.

How properly calling the variable or executing another function from another class in php?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make `$conn` a field, and `$this->conn` to initialize it:

```
public $conn;  // declare $conn field

public function __construct () {
    $this->conn = new Database();  // initialize field
}
```

Comment: then in function i just type $this->conn->connect(); to execute the connect() function?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like this?

```
public $conn;

public function __construct () {
    $this->conn = new Database();
}
```